# List reading doesn't show last entry

Tags: c, list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I made a program that implements a circular and doubly linked list.

```
/*
 * listfech2.c
 * Last Change:  2014-04-23
 * Maintainer:   Lucas de Sena <contact@seninha.net>
 * License:      This file is placed in public domain.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct elemento {
   char dado;
   struct elemento * ant, * prox;
   };

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
   {
   char zero='a';
   int i;
   struct elemento * lista;
   struct elemento *p1, *pinicio;

   p1 = NULL;
   lista = NULL;

   pinicio = malloc (sizeof (struct elemento));
   pinicio -> dado = zero;
   pinicio -> ant = NULL;
   pinicio -> prox = NULL;

   p1 = pinicio;

   for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
      zero++;
      lista = malloc (sizeof (struct elemento));
      lista -> dado = zero;
      lista -> ant = p1;
      lista -> prox = pinicio;
      p1 -> prox = lista;
      printf ("dado atual: %c\n", lista->dado);
      printf ("próximo dado: %c\n", lista->prox->dado);
      printf (" p1->prox->dado: %c\n", p1->prox->dado);
      printf ("===========\n");
      p1 = lista;
   }

   pinicio->ant = lista;
   printf("pinicio->ant: %c\n", pinicio->ant->dado);
   printf("pinicio->dado: %c\n", pinicio->dado);
   printf("pinicio->prox: %c\n", pinicio->prox->dado);
   free (lista);
   p1=pinicio;

   do {
      printf("%c\n", p1->dado);
      p1=p1 -> prox;
   } while (p1 != pinicio );

   return 0;
   }
```

It mount a list of chars from 'a' to 'j'

And after, it prints the characters of the list.

But it doesn't printf 'j', instead it be in the list.

Comment: Got SSCCE? (http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical problem is on this line:

```
  free (lista);
```

Below shows your doubly-linked list when the above 'free()' is called:

[image]

Perhaps this 'free()' line should be deleted?